# Adding Signature Blobs to Crystal Report Form

Tags: crystal-reports

New to Crystal Reports (2013) and learning by doing. I have a client agreement form that has five signature blob fields stored in a column in a separate table. I need to populate each of those five signatures into the correct spot on the form. I tried doing this with formula fields and I'm not having any luck. The field doesn't even show as an option under the SQL Expressions Fields options. If I try it as a regular formula field IF statement I get an error message that says blobs aren't allowed in formulas. If I just add the field to the report, it pulls in only the final signature as there's no conditional statements telling it which signature to grab. How do I go about creating a formula/field/object for each of the five signatures so I can place them on the form? In SQL I'd do a series of SELECT signature_blob WHERE signature_number = X but that doesn't seem to be an option that I'm finding.

Edit: so I think I've managed to do it like this by adding a new database command for each field, but is there a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database view that returns the 5 signatures as 5 columns and a single row + one column for the Agreement ID.

Add that View to the report and join (on Agreement ID).

You can do the same thing directly in the report without a View by adding the Signature table 5 times with different aliases and restrict each alias to a single signature. This would be the same logic as the database view but would be a bit slower.